# APK crashing when downloading from playstore - debug works fine

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm currently having a strange issue with my android project. When I debug my app or if I created a signed APK and install it on my phone, my app works fine. However, after releasing it to play store and installing it from there, the app won't open. It will open with a blank black screen and just minimize itself on all the physical devices I've tested. I can download from play store using bluestack and it runs fine, it just seems to be physical devices that it won't open on.

I'm currently seeing this error appearing in my dev console.

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

`dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass`

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
Unity version     : 2018.3.14f1
Device model      : samsung SM-G950F
Device fingerprint: samsung/dreamltexx/dreamlte:9/PPR1.180610.011/G950FXXS5DSJ1:user/release-keys
Caused by
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3574)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1796)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7050)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver (AppComponentFactory.java:84)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3567)
```

Just to add to this.. I am also seeing these crash logs:

```
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> club.piratetycoon.idleclicker <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000021d54  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+124)
  #01  pc 00000000000a29dc  /system/lib64/libc.so (ifree+1212)
  #02  pc 00000000000a2b08  /system/lib64/libc.so (je_free+120)
  #03  pc 00000000007dc058  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #04  pc 00000000007d7894  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #05  pc 00000000007d7324  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #06  pc 00000000007d5c48  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #07  pc 00000000007d912c  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #08  pc 00000000007d8c10  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #09  pc 00000000007d8730  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #10  pc 00000000007d5414  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #11  pc 00000000004b2cac  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #12  pc 00000000002c1cf0  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #13  pc 000000000000d05c  /system/bin/app_process64 (art::SignalChain::Handler(int, siginfo*, void*)+348)
  #14  pc 000000000000069c  [vdso:0000007a1eec6000]
  #15  pc 00000000005356e0  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #16  pc 0000000000014d74  /system/bin/linker64 (__dl__Z18do_dl_iterate_phdrPFiP12dl_phdr_infomPvES1_+76)
  #17  pc 00000000000145e0  /system/bin/linker64 (__loader_dl_iterate_phdr+48)
  #18  pc 0000000000000f90  /system/lib64/libdl.so (dl_iterate_phdr+8)
  #19  pc 00000000005355e8  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #20  pc 0000000000502afc  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #21  pc 0000000000318580  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #22  pc 00000000002bf9a4  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #23  pc 00000000002c0040  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #24  pc 00000000002bb090  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
  #25  pc 000000000002282c  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/oat/arm64/base.odex (com.unity3d.player.GoogleVrProxy.isQuiting [DEDUPED]+124)
  #26  pc 0000000000561f88  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
  #27  pc 00000000000d0140  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
  #28  pc 00000000002865e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+344)
  #29  pc 00000000002805a4  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+948)
  #30  pc 0000000000532578  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+296)
  #31  pc 0000000000554714  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14484)
  #32  pc 000000000040999c  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c)
  #33  pc 000000000025a0a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.783209430+496)
  #34  pc 000000000025fc20  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
  #35  pc 0000000000280588  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
  #36  pc 000000000053273c  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+204)
  #37  pc 0000000000554794  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
  #38  pc 000000000040915c  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$2.queueIdle+144)
  #39  pc 000000000025a0a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.783209430+496)
  #40  pc 0000000000521978  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1032)
  #41  pc 000000000056b0fc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
  #42  pc 0000000000b2ac3c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.MessageQueue.next+940)
  #43  pc 0000000000b27ecc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+636)
  #44  pc 000000000056224c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+604)
  #45  pc 00000000000d0160  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+232)
  #46  pc 00000000002865e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+344)
  #47  pc 00000000002805a4  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+948)
  #48  pc 000000000053273c  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+204)
  #49  pc 0000000000554794  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
  #50  pc 00000000004093b8  /data/app/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker-KgdTpPx5Q4L5LuUEyrUBvw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run+64)
  #51  pc 000000000025a0a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.783209430+496)
  #52  pc 0000000000521978  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1032)
  #53  pc 000000000056b0fc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
  #54  pc 0000000000561f88  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
  #55  pc 00000000000d0140  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
  #56  pc 00000000004682d8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
  #57  pc 00000000004693a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+424)
  #58  pc 0000000000494c98  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1120)
  #59  pc 0000000000084dc0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
  #60  pc 0000000000023a4c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

Comment: I am also seeing this error when debugging: 2019-11-14 03:37:30.754 23364-23626/club.piratetycoon.idleclicker E/Unity: DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'FirebaseCppApp-5.4.3': The specified module could not be found.
      at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE.PollCallbacks () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Firebase.AppUtil.PollCallbacks () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler.Update () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

Comment: Maybe it depends on the OS version. Have your emulator and device the same android version?

Comment: Are you publishing application as AppBundle system? Then downloaded "APK" differ based on platform. Your device is most probably Android 9, where Bluestack is probably still stuck on Android 5 ... so as @hosseinAmini wrote.

Also, if you use multidex, double check if is correctly set.

Comment: @hosseinAmini Yes its an appbundle.

Comment: I think your app crashes because you are using app bundle(I haven't use app bundle yet). Update your app with APK file and check if your app crashes or not.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the problem here is with firebase API. Please update your app firebase to the production key so that it can run on production apps that are released app on play store.

```
change dev key to ---> production key
```

Comment: Sorry this is all new to me. You mean I have to update something in my project or in my firebase dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

As @hosseinamini pointed out, it was the appbundle that was causing the crash. After I uploaded an apk to the playstore, the crash disappeared.